# add button should work for each form-holder saparatly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

```
***<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7     /css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="order-details-booking">
    <blockquote>Self-order Menu</blockquote>
      <div class="form-holder col-xs-14">
        <div class="input-field col s4">
            <input type="text" id="item-" placeholder="Item Code"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s2">
            <input type="text" id="item-code" placeholder="Qty" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s5">
            <input type="text" id="item-code" placeholder="Remarks" />
        </div>
        <div class="col s1">
            <i class="material-icons remove">- remove</i>
        </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-holder-append"></div>
      <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                      <i class="material-icons add">+ add</i>
        </div></div>
</div>
<div id="order-details-booking2">
    <blockquote>Self-order Menu</blockquote>
      <div class="form-holder col-xs-1">
        
        <div class="input-field col s4">
            <input type="text" id="item-" placeholder="Item Code"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s2">
            <input type="text" id="item-code" placeholder="Qty" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s5">
            <input type="text" id="item-code" placeholder="Remarks" />
        </div>
        <div class="col s1">
            <i class="material-icons remove">- remove</i>
        </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-holder-append"></div>
      <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                      <i class="material-icons add">+ add</i>
        </div></div>
</div>
</html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7    /js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
var id_count = 1;
$('.add').on('click', function() {
var source = $('.form-holder:first'), clone = source.clone();
clone.find(':input').attr('id', function(i, val) {
  return val + id_count;
});
clone.appendTo('.form-holder-append');
id_count++;
});
//button for add second holder
var id_count2 = 1;
$('.add').on('click', function() {
var source = $('.form-holder:first'), clone = source.clone();
clone.find(':input').attr('id', function(i, val) {
  return val + id_count2;`enter code here`
});
clone.appendTo('.form1-holder-append');
id_count++;
});
// Removing Form Field
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
var closest = $(this).closest('.form-holder').remove();
});
</script>***
```

webpage contain 2 form holder, when ever i click add button the action should be performed to each holder separately, but now the if we press add button, the it add form to both form holder.I shared the code in above, I hope I may get help as soon as possible, Thank for help..

---

---

---

---

---

********It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

if you only have two formholders you can solve this by useing unique classes.

```
var id_count = 1;
$('.add1').on('click', function() {
var source = $('.form-holder1:first'), clone = source.clone();
clone.find(':input').attr('id', function(i, val) {
  return val + id_count;
});
clone.appendTo('.form-holder-append1');
id_count++;
});
//button for add second holder
var id_count2 = 1;
$('.add2').on('click', function() {
var source = $('.form-holder2:first'), clone = source.clone();
clone.find(':input').attr('id', function(i, val) {
  return val + id_count2;`enter code here`
});
clone.appendTo('.form-holder-append2');
id_count++;
});
// Removing Form Field
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
var closest = $(this).closest('.form-holder').remove();
});
```

if you have a dynamic amount of formholders you should use a each() function and count the formholders and each element inside with eq(). This results in only one function for all formholders, independently how many.